# How to call a function when POST button is pressed on Django Rest Api

Tags: django, python-3.x, onclick, django-rest-framework

I have a Django rest api which you can upload a file and an id:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njuTI.png)

I want to call a function when post button is pressed in order to do some stuff with the uploaded file. How can I do this in django rest platform?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .validators import validate_file_extension



class Uplist(models.Model):

    report_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key= True)
    application = models.FileField(blank=False, null=False, validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from api import models


class UplistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Uplist
        fields = ('application', 'report_id',)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ListUps.as_view()),
    url(r'^$', views.ListUps.as_view()),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ListDetails.as_view()),
]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser

from api import models
from . import serializers


class ListUps(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    queryset = models.Uplist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UplistSerializer

class ListDetails(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = models.Uplist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UplistSerializer
```

validators.py

```
def validate_file_extension(value):
    import os
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]  # [0] returns path+filename
    valid_extensions = ['.csv']
    if not ext.lower() in valid_extensions:
        raise ValidationError(u'Unsupported file extension.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In urls add pattern

```
path('someurl', SomeClass.as_view()),
```

In your view.py

```
class SomeClass(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    ....
```

When you call post function you goto this view. You can perform your tasks here.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
class ListUps(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    queryset = models.Uplist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UplistSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    #added function here    
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```